# Pylint warning - W5304(Missing-Test-Class)

Tags: python, pylint

I have a function with a doctest and it prints some kind of warning with PyLint:

```
ID:W5304(missing-test-class) <function name>: No test class (has function doctest). Should be one of <some modules>.
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to be able to reproduce easily this in another module and I cannot post this proprietary code.

Anyone has an idea about this warning mean ?

Comment: That's not one of the built-in PyLint error messages - you can see all the codes [here](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/all-codes). I guess your project has defined its own codes to enforce its coding standards, one of which seems to be that all classes need their own test classes.

Comment: Ah that would explain why I cannot google it

Comment: @Daniel Roseman: If you put your answer I will accept it

Comment: Have a look in the project's `.pylintrc`